# Регулярное выражение для валидации буквенно-числовой последовательности

Tags: регулярные-выражения, валидация

Люди, умеющие составлять регэкспы, вы из космоса к нам прилетели! :)

Думается мне, что нужно иметь специфический склад ума, чтобы формализовать и реализовать regexp-валидаторы.

Итак, моя задача – создать валидатор следующих последовательностей:

- HJ-1648
- KM-6617
- UY-7789

*Условия задачи:*

1. Префикс артикула должен начинаться только с приведенных пар заглавных букв. То есть ничего кроме HJ, KM и UY быть не может.
2. За буквенной последоватьностью должен идти минус в качестве разделителя.
3. Далее идет числовая последовательность из четырёх цифр, которая не может начинаться с нуля.
4. Длина получившейся строки составляет строго семь символов.

Предварительные поиски решения ничем не увенчались. Не от того что ленив иль небрежен, а от того что надо лететь в другую галактику чтобы понять ЭТО :) Потратил полтора часа на изучение манов на англоязычных и русскоязычных ресурсах, но осилил только `^[A-Z]$`.

Comment: А зачем regexp, если можно проверить длину, три допустимых префикса и то что потом 4 цифры? И не нужно другого склада ума, и код гораздо понятнее.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов 1. regex проще. 2. regex в одинаковой степени подходит для разных мест. Например, в случае сайта, один и тот же regex может использоваться на сервере, в js-коде на клиенте и в атрибуте pattern, проверку которого современные браузеры выполнят самостоятельно.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, префиксов восемдесят семь :) Их надо загонять в массив и проверять в цикле. Кроме того надо писать валидатор, проверяющий что длина числовых значений ровно 4 символа. Числовое значение 0600 машина не поймет, а для этого надо будет использовать строку. Да и что может быть проще одной (!) строчки кода `if not TRegEx.IsMatch(s, '^(HJ|KM|UY)-[1-9][0-9]{3}$') then`?

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown Вы уж определитесь - ровно три или 87 :-) И да, такие простые regexp, которые непонятно как составить - как?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, 3 - это упрощение для вопроса. Для 87 будет то же самое ведь.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, я не учусь на первом курсе универа :) И у меня нет учебных задачек. Вопрос, понятное дело, основан на реальной задаче, которую я по понятным соображениям приводить не стану. Ответ на вопрос - лишь прототип. Сейчас я реализую код, основанный на этом прототипе. Quertiy лишь подсказал мне способ реализации.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Думаю, так... Мне даже проверять лень...

```
^(HJ|KM|UY)-[1-9][0-9]{3}$
```

Comment: Опционально можно заменить `[0-9]` на `\d` и сделать скобки не захватываемыми (это уж если и правда нужно), а так все хорошо и проверять не надо :)

Comment: @tutankhamun, скобки - да, можно, но не вижу смысла. `\d` в некоторых языках будет позволять региональные цифры, что вроде не хорошо по вопросу. К тому же, `\d` эстетически не очень смотрится рядом с `[1-9]`.

Comment: @Qwertiy большое спасибо. Особенно впечатлили три минуты разницы между вопросом и ответом ;)

Comment: С таким подробным ТЗ и маленьким объемом работы немудрено. Вот бы такие проекты на фрилансе были... Да подороже... :)

Comment: @tutankhamun это конечно же не проект, а лишь та область знаний, которой Qwertiy (в конкретной постановке вопроса) владеет лучше всех. Мы все разработчики с опытом, но иногда возникают задачи, которые не стоит брать "в лоб" по разным, вполне обоснованым причинам. Иногда стоит просто спросить у коллег, которые вполне могут решать эти задачи много раз в течение дня ;)